# Looping through a dictionary in javascript with a list within the values

Tags: javascript

Not sure how to parse through a list of strings within a loop regarding this dictionary.

```js
var student_nicknames = [    
    {name: "William",  nickname: "Bill"},
    {name: "Joseph",   nickname: "Joe"},
    {name: "Maria",    nickname: "Mary"},
    {name: "Richard",  nickname: ["Rick", "Ricky"]},
    {name: "Elizabeth",  nickname: ["Liz", "Lisa", "Beth"]}
];

total_nicknames = function(){
    student_nicknames.forEach(function(student) {
       console.log(student.nickname); 
    });
}
```

Output

```
Bill
Joe
Mary
[ 'Rick', 'Ricky' ]
[ 'Liz', 'Lisa', 'Beth' ]
```

Desired Output

```
Bill
Joe
Mary
Rick
Ricky
Liz
Lisa
Beth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to have an `if` condition to check if nickname property of each student is an array or not, if it is an array, then you can loop through it and print each item individually, otherwise follow your logic.

```
var student_nicknames = [
  { name: "William", nickname: "Bill" },
  { name: "Joseph", nickname: "Joe" },
  { name: "Maria", nickname: "Mary" },
  { name: "Richard", nickname: ["Rick", "Ricky"] },
  { name: "Elizabeth", nickname: ["Liz", "Lisa", "Beth"] }
];

const total_nicknames = function () {
  student_nicknames.forEach(function (student) {
    if (Array.isArray(student.nickname)) { // <- HERE
      student.nickname.forEach((e) => console.log(e));
    } else {
      console.log(student.nickname);
    }
  });
};

total_nicknames();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether the type is an Array or not:

```
total_nicknames = function(){
    student_nicknames.forEach(function(student) {
        if (Array.isArray(student.nickname)) {
          student.nickname.forEach(function (nickname) {
            console.log(nickname)
          })
        } else {
          console.log(student.nickname);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` to get only *nicknames* and then use `flat()` to *flatten* the array.

```js
var student = [    
    {name: "William",  nickname: "Bill"},
    {name: "Joseph",   nickname: "Joe"},
    {name: "Maria",    nickname: "Mary"},
    {name: "Richard",  nickname: ["Rick", "Ricky"]},
    {name: "Elizabeth",  nickname: ["Liz", "Lisa", "Beth"]}
];
console.log(student.map(({nickname})=>nickname).flat())
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution based on recursion.

```
function total_nicknames(student_nicknames) {
    for(let i = 0; i < student_nicknames.length; i++){
      let student = student_nicknames[i];
        if(typeof student === 'object' && student !== null) {
          if(Array.isArray(student.nickname)){
            total_nicknames(student.nickname);
          }else {
            console.log(student.nickname);
          }
        }else {
          console.log(student);
        }
    }
  }


console.log(total_nicknames(student_nicknames));

/* output */
// "Bill"
// "Joe"
// "Mary"
// "Rick"
// "Ricky"
// "Liz"
// "Lisa"
// "Beth"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a small recursive loop, by calling the `total_nicknames` function again, if `student.nickname` is an array. You also need to use `||` (OR) operator, to get the nickname (which would be a string, if it loops over the array) and not `undefined` (since string object doesn't have any nickname method/property).

```js
var student_nicknames = [{
    name: "William",
    nickname: "Bill"
  },
  {
    name: "Joseph",
    nickname: "Joe"
  },
  {
    name: "Maria",
    nickname: "Mary"
  },
  {
    name: "Richard",
    nickname: ["Rick", "Ricky"]
  },
  {
    name: "Elizabeth",
    nickname: ["Liz", "Lisa", "Beth"]
  }
];

total_nicknames = function(arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(student) {
    if (Array.isArray(student.nickname)) {
      total_nicknames(student.nickname)
    } else
      console.log((student.nickname || student));
  });
}

total_nicknames(student_nicknames);
```